# Sublime Text 3 Theme Tabs-font

Tags: text, tabs

After I installed and activated Ayu theme,tabs look ugly,
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95x0y.jpg)

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Change theme instead, I personally like **Eiffel**. Do give a try.
And if you still want to use the same theme and want to change the color of the tab, Do refer to this link https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-background-tab-color-its-too-subtle/4673 Hope it helped.

**So basically, You'll need to edit the appropriate images within the /Packages/Theme - Default/ folder**